# Node.js HTTPS Secure Error

Tags: https, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to create a secure node.js server to use with my site that is using ssl (https).

```
const crypto = require('crypto'),
      fs = require("fs"),
      http = require("http");

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('/home/privatekey.pem');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('/home/certificate.pem');

var credentials = crypto.createCredentials({key: privateKey.toString(), cert: certificate.toString()});

var handler = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
};

var server = http.createServer();
server.setSecure(credentials);
server.addListener("request", handler);
server.listen(8084);
```

But when I start my server, I get the following error:

```
node.js:116
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
TypeError: Object #<Server> has no method 'setSecure'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/meshdev/public_html/js/node/server/test.js:16:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:380:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:386:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:312:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:273:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:399:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:108:26)
```

My server works great without the `server.setSecure(credentials);` line. I am running node.js(V0.4.1).

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

HTTPS implementation was re-done in Node.JS 0.4. See the corresponding docs at [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/tls.html#tLS_).

Example from the docs:

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem')
};

tls.createServer(options, function (s) {
  s.write("welcome!\n");
  s.pipe(s);
}).listen(8000);
```

Comment: @schaermu - Thanks for the reply. It has stopped my node server from returning errors on startup but I am now getting this error thrown up when I connect client side: http://pastebin.com/ECf1fxLB Any ideas?

Comment: could you post the content of `s.authorizationError` ? There should be a better error message when a tls handshake is failing (according the docs).

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I am using this code for the server: http://pastebin.com/FHmVpPS9. And this code for the client side connection: http://pastebin.com/xxcL7Rqv. The node server no longer errors, but the client side cannot connect.

Comment: p.s. I am using socket.io to connect to the server.

Comment: oh, didn't see the socket.io tag ;) maybe you want to take a look at the [ssl-example](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node/tree/master/example) of socket.io. I never implemented a secure socket.io server/client, can't help you out with my own experience.

Comment: Does this work for you in IE8?  When I try this in Chrome or FF, it's all fine.  In IE8 the browser freezes for minutes and then comes up with random jQuery errors.

Comment: Ignoring the fact that this isn't for socket.io, this example isn't HTTPS, it's just a TLS TCP implementation. You'll want to send back some kind of response header first. See the node.js docs for https example: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/https.html

Answer (score 3):

this setup allowed me to connect to my socket.io server ssl (HTTPS/WSS)

```
http=require('https'),io=require('socket.io'),fs=require('fs');

var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('ssl/nginx.key');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('ssl/nginx.crt');
var options = {key: privateKey,cert: certificate};
var server = http.createServer(options);
server.listen(3000);
io = io.listen(server);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on the https secure with the ssl here is the working code for making the https and http

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var debug = require('debug')('expressapp');
var app = require('../app');
var CONSTANTS = require('../config/CONSTANTS.js');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var certificate =fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt',{encoding:'utf8'},function(err, data ) {
  console.log( data );});
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.key',{encoding:'utf8'},function(err, data ) {
  console.log( data );});


var credentials = {
  key: privateKey,
  cert: certificate,
  rejectUnauthorized:false
};

// UNCOMMENT THIS LINE AFTER INSTALLING CA CERTIFICATE
 //credentials.ca = fs.readFileSync('ssl/server.crt', 'utf8');;

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

  httpServer.listen(CONSTANTS.PORT.HTTP, function() {
    console.log('HTTP server listening on port ' + CONSTANTS.PORT.HTTP);
   })  ;

httpsServer.listen(CONSTANTS.PORT.HTTPS, function() {
  console.log('HTTPS server listening on port ' + CONSTANTS.PORT.HTTPS);
});
```