# starttls on node.js > 0.4.0

Tags: node.js, xmpp, ssl, node-xmpp

I came across this thread [Node.js HTTPS Secure Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136353/node-js-https-secure-error) which mentions that the tls module is the way to do TLS on node now. It seems that setSecure() has been dropped. I'm trying to do a STARTTLS for XMPP. This means that the socket will be upgraded midway. How do I go about doing this on node.js > 0.4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: https://gist.github.com/848444

Comment: so, I tried doing that, but the thing is that event handlers have already been attached on the socket and after TLS, the don't seem to be firing on it again. Do I need to reattach these handlers or attach handlers on something else (return value of pipe)?

Comment: okay. got it working!! I need to reattach all handlers to the cleartext object returned by starttls(). node-xmpp should have SSL support in node.js>=0.4.0 now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a close look at the lib/tls.js file in the Node Github repo.

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/tls.js#L949-992

Another resource that you really might like is here:

https://github.com/andris9/rai/blob/master/lib/starttls.js