# start TLS over TCP server stream at node.JS

Tags: node.js

Trying to write analog of starttls https://gist.github.com/848444 but for server stream.

Since setSecure was removed there are no easy way to make it;

So there are an TCP server, and I need to start encryption at one moment, starttls don't work for this case.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146666/starttls-on-node-js-0-4-0/10833341#10833341

Comment: Worth mentioning that this question is anachronistic now, since node.js has this built in for some time.