# How to hide login and password using angular cors and nodejs

Tags: angular, cors, httpclient

Good morning guys, I need some help.

I am developing an application to study and try to apply in the future in the company. I am already with my backend (nodejs api rest) running on iis and I am creating my web application in angular 4. The problem is that I am doing my authentication screen and if I use tools like wireshark I can capture the login and the password.

How can I hide this?

```
login(login: string, senha: string): Observable<User> {
   const headers = new HttpHeaders();

   headers
     .append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
     .append('Accept', 'q=0.8;application/json;q=0.9');

   return this.http
              .post<User>(`${BASE_URL}/sign-in`, { username: login, password: senha }, {headers: headers, withCredentials: true})
              .do(user => (this.user = user));
}
```

how to make the wireshark does not show the user and password
[wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YibXR.png)

Comment: You’re probably looking for the Portuguese SO, this is English only site

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I am doing my authentication screen and if I use tools like wireshark I can capture the login and the password.

In order to avoid that, you want to encrypt your traffic with **HTTPS**. This is actually a backend / operational issue and rather unrelated to Angular.

First you need a certificate. For testing purposes this can be a self-signed certificate that you created yourself (e.g. [with OpenSSL](https://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html)).
Then you have to set up your backend properly (e.g. with [Express](https://blog.cloudboost.io/everything-about-creating-an-https-server-using-node-js-2fc5c48a8d4e), plain [NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136353/node-js-https-secure-error?lq=1), or [IIS](http://brianflove.com/2014/12/02/enable-https-on-iis/)).

If necessary at all the only changes you have to apply to your Angular code will be adding *s*'s to hardcoded URLs (from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`).

Comment: Yes.
My backend is already configured this way. The problem is in the fronend.
When the application communicates with the backend I get the data through wireshark.
From the backend to the AD is already hidden this data.

Comment: example is the browser proxy / login box when you need to log in to access the internet.

Comment: This has nothing to do with AD or any other communication your backend does. Basically, your `${BASE_URL}` needs to be an HTTPS url. Try out this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/R4XLKA5kMLAN9juhcIa2) and verify that the traffic to `https://httpbin.org/post` is encrypted.